# check if keyguard is enabled i.e. currently active from android application

Tags: android, api

How can i check from my android application whether there is a keyguard enabled right now? I mean normally when screen goes off Android enables the keyguard, so next time you wake up you have keyguard screen infront of you. So I just want to know from the application that if there is a key guard enabled or not.

I had a look on keyguardmanager.java but it does not have that API.

Answer (score 5):

Get the `KeyGuardManager` system service, and call `inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()` function.
See Documentation [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode%28%29).

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);  

Log.v(TAG,""+keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode());
```

I tested on my HTC G1, it works.

Comment: Call requires API level 16